# How to switch image if DIV is not hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following JQuery which displays a menu if a DIV is pressed:

```
var pull = $('#mmTrigger');
menu = $('.ulMM');
menuHeight = menu.height();

$(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dvMain">
        <ul class="ulMM specClear">
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">About</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="mmTrigger"><img src="nav-icon.png" class="imgMenu" /></div>
    </div>
```

I modified the script to this:

```
    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     menu.slideToggle();
     if (menu.is(':hidden')) {
         $(".imgMenu").attr("src", "nav-icon.png");
     } else {
         $(".imgMenu").attr("src", "iconx.png");
     }
 });
```

But after clicking the DIV, the `X` stays and doesn't go back to the `nav-icon.png` once the menu is closed.

How can I resolve it so that the `X` changes to the menu icon.

I added this statement: `alert (menu.is(':hidden'));` it always returns false.

Comment: Yuo should check it in slideToggle complete callback, i guess

Comment: Shouldnt it be: if ( ! menu.is(":visible"))

Comment: didn't work :/ Not sure why

Comment: Offtopic. You are doing too much in javascript what should be done via CSS. `$('mmTrigger').click(function(){$(this).closest('.dvMain).toggleClass('closed');})` - that's it. The rest is CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I agree with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the icon after the `slideToggle` animation has stopped. You can do this in `callback` like this:

```
$(pull).on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle(function () {
        // slideToggles callback
        if (menu.is(':hidden')) {
            $(".imgMenu").attr("src", "nav-icon.png");
        } else {
            $(".imgMenu").attr("src", "iconx.png");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Simple and quick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try changing image on complete of slide toggle: see here:http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var pull = $('#mmTrigger');
 menu = $('.ulMM');
 menuHeight = menu.height();

 $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      menu.slideToggle("slow", function() {
      alert( ! menu.is(":visible") );
     if (! menu.is(":visible")) {
          $(".imgMenu").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png");// icons added to show demo use your own icons.
      } else {
          $(".imgMenu").attr("src", "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png");
      }
      });
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dvMain">
        <ul class="ulMM specClear">
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">About</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="mmTrigger"><img src="https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png" class="imgMenu" /></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I +1 the post because this is also an option which works.